# Importar $http en constructor ($http is not defined)

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2, ionic-framework

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición **`AJAX`** desde **`Ionic`**, tengo este html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Prueba AJAX
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <div center text-center>
    <button ion-button (click)="traerInfo()">
        Informacion ajax
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Y tengo el siguiente `.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-prueba',
    templateUrl: 'prueba.html'
})

export class PruebaPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alerCtrl: AlertController) {

    }

    traerInfo() {
        $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt")
        .then(function(response) {
            let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
                title: 'Informacion obtenida!',
                message: response,
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alert.present()
        });

    }
}
```

Me está tirando error de que la variable `$http` no está definida. Pero ya probé incluyéndola en el `constructor`:

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alerCtrl: AlertController, public http: $http)
```

O incluso haciendo lo mismo importando todo como explican acá:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Y haciendo en el constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alerCtrl: AlertController, public http: Http)
```

Pero tampoco resultó...

Se me agotaron las opciones, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: intentastes asi `import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` y luego `constructor(http: Http)` chequea que esta la Http esta en mayuscula la primera ademas que en el constructor cuando lo haces de esa forma esta haciendo esto`this.http = http;` y cuando llames  la funcion get debes hacerlo con`this.http.get`; dime si te funciono para agregarlo como respuesta @Genarito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus pruebas estuvieron casi cerca, el error que tenias era la forma de invocar el metodo get; te explicare en detalle que es lo que debes hacer

primero debes importar la libreria `http`  y `Response` de **`angular`**

> la `Http` realiza el llamado y la de `Response` obtiene el resultado

```
   import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

luego agregarla al constructor, y la declaras

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alerCtrl: AlertController , private http: Http) {
```

finalmente debes cambiar la linea de donde invocas el metodo `get` por que ya es un `objeto` dentro de la clase y quedaria algo como

```
this.http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt")
```

> recuerda que cuando haces una linea en el constructor puedes hacerlo de manera convencional que es asignar las variables dentro del constructor y luego ejecutar una funcion; en el caso de `angular2` al realizar una linea como `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController` estas declarando en la clase una variable `navCtrl` el tipo de visibilidad es `Publica` y asignando el objeto `NavController`

tu codigo debe quedar mas o menos asi:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-prueba',
    templateUrl: 'prueba.html'
})

export class PruebaPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alerCtrl: AlertController , private http: Http) {

    }
    traerInfo() {
        this.http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_info.txt")
        .map(function(response:Response) => {
             console.log(response.json());
            let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
                title: 'Informacion obtenida!',
                message: response.json(),
                buttons: ['Ok']
            });
            alert.present()
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Mil gracias! Lo puse igual que como dijiste solo que en vez de map() uso subscribe() y error() y funciona de 10! Saludos!